# SQLite registering VFS causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to register a [VFS](https://sqlite.org/vfs.html) in SQLite:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int vfs_open(sqlite3_vfs* vfs, const char *zName, sqlite3_file* file, int flags, int *pOutFlags)
{

  std::cout << "Hello open";
  return SQLITE_OK;
}
int vfs_access(sqlite3_vfs* vfs, const char *zName, int flags, int *pResOut)
{
  std::cout << "Hello access";
  return 0;
}

int main () {
  static sqlite3_vfs vfs;
  vfs.iVersion = 1;
  vfs.szOsFile = 1000;
  vfs.zName = "foo";
  vfs.xOpen = vfs_open;
  vfs.xAccess = vfs_access;

  sqlite3_vfs_register(&vfs, 0);

  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_open_v2("db.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, "foo");
}
```

But when I run this code I get Segmentation Fault:

```
$ g++ test.cc libsqlite3.dylib 
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any help what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A couple of suggestions - possibly your trace writes aren't being flushed before the crash, use `std:endl` to flush them. There is also a ton of methods you aren't defining in your structure, possibly sqlite is calling one of those (`xFullPathname` springs to mind), you might need to add dummy functions for the rest. I couldn't find any documentation on the minumum set of functions you have to define.

Comment: @TheDark : This is spot on. Providing a dummy `xFullPathname` implementation causes the program not to crash anymore, but at the same time I still don't see the prints from `vfs_open`. The OP should probably check the return value of `sqlite3_open_v2`. BTW : You might want to compile your own SQLite on the side with debug symbols in order to find out where it crashes on VFS functions that you don't have - that's what I did.

Comment: @TheDark thanks that actually worked. Please answer and I can give you +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sqlite3_vfs` structure has pointers for a lot of functions. I couldn't find any documentation on the minimum set of functions you have to define, so it is probably safer to assume that they are all required, even just as stub functions.

In your case, I guess that sqlite is calling one of the functions you haven't defined yet (possibly `xFullPathname`), causing an attempt to run a function at NULL.